# Issue getting HTTP response Status code from Headers while using curl

Tags: curl, http-status-codes

Am using curl to fetch some data from a payment gateway,, the gateway returns 500 status code at times and 200 status code in the headers at other times. I am trying to get the status code from the headers using curl but it is showing zero (which is the exit code) instead of 200 or 500 (status code).

Am using **curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);** which aint working...

**Curl function**

```
public function global_Curl_payStat($data, $url, $try = 1)
    {
        //dd($_ENV['API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP'] . '/' . $url);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ($_ENV['API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP'] . '/' . $url));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //Prevents usage of a cached version of the URL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
        //Listen for status code to see if 200 or 500
        $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        dd($statusCode);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `curl_getinfo()` is coming before you have actually called it with `curl_exec()`. There is no info until you execute :)

```
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
//Listen for status code to see if 200 or 500
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```